# Pronunciation of 'Fen', 'Fan', and 'Fang' in English

Tags: pronunciation

Can someone describe the difference in pronunciation between these three English words: Fen, Fan and Fang.

'Fen' is the easiest, because it's just like the first syllable in 'fence'. What other common / easy-to-pronounce words have the syllables 'Fan' or 'Fang' in them?

I can hear the difference in all three (based on listening to soundbites on dictionary websites), although I can't really describe the difference, it just sounds 'different'. And I can't seem to reliably pronounce the difference.

Apparently 'Fen' = /fen/, 'Fan' = /fæn/ and 'Fang' = /fæŋ/

What is the difference between a 'n' and a 'ŋ'? Are there any other common English word pairs that I could use to grasp the difference between 'e' and 'æ', and between 'n' and 'ŋ'. Any tips on practicing these similar-ish sounds?

Comment: Those aren’t quite right. Only *fan* is what you have, /fæn/, like in *ran* or *fancy*.  *Fen* is /fɛn/ like in *wren* or *men*, while *fang* is /feŋ/ like in *rain* or *same*.  So they each have a different vowel.

Comment: @tchrist. I have never heard "fang" pronounced as /feŋ/. In my (British) English "fan" and "fang" have the same vowel.

Comment: @fdb There’s a great deal of vowel neutralization before resonants: think *merry–marry-Mary* or *pin–pen*. In this case, the tense and lax phonemic distinction is completely neutralized before /ŋ/, so there are no minimal pairs for [æŋ], [ɛŋ], and [eŋ]. Those are all allophones and changing which one you say does not make it a different word. In North America, this is often [eŋ], but it is not a different word if you swap in one of the other two vowels.

Comment: @tchrist: This is true, but only for some dialects (you never mention that it doesn't apply to all of them). Historical /ɛŋ/ is uncommon, but does occur in some words (such as *strength, length*) and it is kept distinct from historical /æŋ/ in some dialects. For speakers with such a distinction, a minimal pair might be the name "Ang" (in "Ang Lee") and the IPA letter "eng." Using /e/ or /ɛ/ in *fen* is a notational choice; there are also some phonetic justifications for using the symbol /e/ when transcribing some dialects.

Comment: 'pen', 'pan', 'pang'. 'Ben', 'ban', 'bang!'. 'den', 'Dan', 'dang!'. 'ten', 'tan', 'tang'

Comment: @sumelic yes I'm a native speaker. I don't know very much linguistics, so the rest of what you say doesn't make heaps of sense to me.

Comment: @tchrist I got them from http://dictionary.reference.com/. The sound bites there sound right when i hear them, so I assume they are correct. But I guess there may be regional differences (I'm not sure if dictionary.reference is us english or american english)

Comment: @Mitch yes that's kind of like the examples I was hoping someone could provide. So in your examples, I say the -en/-an pairs very differently, but the -an/-ang pairs very similarly. Thanks!

Comment: @epetorti They are examples of triples that are actual words in English (or names or interjections). But if you were pronouncing them wrong to begin with, the new ones won't help you to pronounce them correctly. You need to hear people actually say them (and have someone listen to you and correct).

Comment: @mitch Wasn't very clear in my earlier reply. I can say those words just fine. I wanted examples of other words with similar sounds to try and understand what the difference between the sounds are. I'm guessing most of you guys on this sub probably have some background in linguistics... but for me, when words sound different, i can't necessarily tell what the difference actually is...

Comment: Your transcriptions are absolutely correct for Standard British as transcribed by most phoneticians, dictionaries and EFL publications.

Answer (score 3):

It's dialectual difference that caused the vowel of "fang" to be different than "fan".

[Short a dialectual difference, in North American English (opening the footnote gives your answer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_short_A#.2F.C3.A6.2F_tensing)

Now let's get on to differentiating /ŋ/ and /n/.

/ŋ/ is a velar nasal, i.e. a nasal sound made with the same parts of the mouth as the hard G sound /g/.

/n/ meanwhile is an alveolar nasal, made with the same parts of the mouth as the D sound /d/.

I actually noticed this when on dictionaries like Wiktionary would all transcribe "dragon"'s A vowel as short A, even when it didn't sound like short A for every person in my life I spoke with. (I am a native speaker) I asked why so, and as an answer they gave me a link to that Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a native English speaker (American-Californian), and I pronounce the 'a' of 'fan' and 'fang' the same way. Like you said, the 'e' of 'fen' is pronounced like in 'fence.' The 'a' of 'fan' and 'fang' is more open (that is, the mouth is held more open) and the front of the tongue is lower than the 'e' sound in 'fen.'